# Is it possible to detect if an app is launched from adb?

Tags: android, adb

I develop an android app and I want to execute a certain function if the app is launched from adb.
When the app is launched from the device this function will not be executed.

UPDATE
I use the below code

```
        if ((Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED) != 0) {
        PluginResult.Status status = PluginResult.Status.OK;
        String result = "";
        result = "ok";
        return new PluginResult(status, result);
        } 

        if ((Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED) == 0) {
        PluginResult.Status status = PluginResult.Status.ERROR;
        String result = "";
        result = "error";
        return new PluginResult(status, result);
        }
```

but i receive always ok.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Nothing would stop the user from setting the flag when launching the activity via `adb` as well.

Answer (score 0):

**App launch from OS:**

1. First thing  is that if you launch the app from the launcher icon, the Intent includes the CATEGORY "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER".
2. When you launch via the launcher icon, the Intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED (0x200000) is set.

**App Lauch from ADB:**

1. The adb shell case it is not.(adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName)
2. In the adb shell case FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED is not.

This will solve your question.all the best

Answer (score 0):

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` is a bitmask and a constant. The proper way to check if the flag is set is:

```
if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED) != 0) {
...
```